# Writing Python Script from Batch Script is not working for one command

Tags: python, batch-file, klocwork

I'm trying to convert batch script into python script.
This is batch script, which is calling Klockwork exe on the project specified building it.

```
%KwPath%\Kwinject -o kwinjectmp.out msbuild %BaseProjPath%/CodingGuide.vcxproj /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x64" /p:CLToolExe=cl.exe /p:CLToolPath=%VSBinPath%
```

I have write equivalent python script for it.

```
args = KwPath + '\\Kwinject.exe sync -o ' + 'kwinjectmp.out' + 'msbuild ' + BaseProject + '\\' + ProjectFolder + '\\' + ProjectName + '/t:Rebuild /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x64" /p:CLToolExe=cl.exe /p:CLToolPath=' + VSBinPath
print(args)
subprocess.call(args, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Where **I have declared BaseProject, VSBinPath, KwPath correctly**. But the exectuion is not happening as it is happening in BatchScript, Basically script is not giving any output/working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

spaces between arguments may be absent because of your usage. try this:

```
import os
path1 = os.path.join(KwPath, 'Kwinject.exe')
path2 = os.path.join(BaseProject, ProjectFolder, ProjectName)
subprocess.call([
        path1,
        'sync',
        '-o', 'kwinjectmp.out',
        'msbuild',
        path2,
        '/t:Rebuild',
        '/p:Configuration="Release"',
        '/p:Platform="x64"',
        '/p:CLToolExe=cl.exe',
        '/p:CLToolPath=' + VSBinPath
    ], 
    shell=True, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
)
```